# Probability of Union of 4 or More Elements

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following problem:

> Given $P(A)=0.2$, $P(B)=0.4$, $P(C)=0.8$, $P(D)=0.5$, find $P(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)$

And the final answer should be 0.952

I know how to find the union of two and three elements (for 2, its: $A+B-AB$), but the formula becomes clumsy after 3. The best things I've found says that to find the union for n elements, I add as follows $$0.2-(0.2\times0.4)+(0.2\times0.4\times0.8)-(0.2\times0.4\times0.8\times0.5) = 0.152$$ which is wrong.

What is a good general rule for n events?

Comment: Are A, B, C, and D independent events? If not, you need more data.

Comment: Yes they're independent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following identity:

$$\mathbb{P}( A \cup B \cup C \cup D) = 1 - \mathbb{P}( (A \cup B \cup C \cup D)^c ) = 
  1 - \mathbb{P}( A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c \cap D^c )$$

Here $A^c$ means complement of set $A$.

Given independence of events $\mathbb{P}( A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c \cap D^c ) = \mathbb{P}( A^c )  \mathbb{P}( B^c ) \mathbb{P}( C^c ) \mathbb{P}( D^c )$. Now:

$$\mathbb{P}( A \cup B \cup C \cup D) = 1 - (1-0.2)(1-0.4)(1-0.8)(1-0.5) = 0.952$$

Comment: And note that it's very important (as Sasha mentions) that the events be independent. Otherwise the answer could be anywhere from 0.8 to 1, depending on the specifics.

Comment: Is this something that could work with n elements? (I won't need this for my studies, but I'm curious).

Comment: Yes, it would, because $ ( \cup_{i=1}^n A_i )^c = \cap_{i=1}^n A_i^c$.

Comment: will this work for probabilities for union of sets extending to n?

Answer (score 0):

The question you pose cannot be solved; all that can be said is that
$$
\max\{P(A), P(B), P(C), P(D)\} = 0.8 \leq P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D) \leq 1
$$
However, the answer $0.952$ that you give corresponds to the case when $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are *independent* events.  Did you leave out this important piece of information when you typed in your question?

Generally, if $A_i, 1 \leq i \leq n$ are *independent* events, then
using DeMorgan's laws
$$
P(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) = 1 - P((A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n)^c) = 1 - P(A_1^c\cap\cdots \cap A_n^c) = 1 - P(A_1^c)\cdots P(A_n^c)
$$
In order to avoid unnecessary arithmetic calculations, it is of the utmost importance that the expression on the right  *not*
be expressed as
$$
1 - [1-P(A_1)]\cdots[1-P(A_n)]
$$
and multiplied out to get
$$P(A_1) + \cdots + P(A_n) - [P(A_1)P(A_2) + P(A_1)P(A_3) + \cdots P(A_{n-1})P(A_n)] + \cdots
$$
The latter is an expression based on the *principle of inclusion and exclusion* and is a lot more work to evaluate.

Comment: ...lot more work and would need lot more data too :-)

Comment: @Srivatsan  Yes to lot more work, but no to lot more data.  The general inclusion-exclusion principle needs lot more data since it needs, for example, the value of $P(A_iA_j)$.  But for _independent_ events, $P(A_iA_j) = P(A_i)P(A_j)$, and similarly for all the compound events, and so the inclusion-exclusion principle _can_ be used if we know just the values of $P(A_1), \ldots, P(A_n)$.  But, as I pointed out and we agree, it is a lot more work than just computing the product of the probabilities of the complementary events and subtracting from $1$