# Calculating probability of 'at least one event occurring' for n independent events

Tags: probability

I want to create an algorithm to calculate the OR of n independent events, anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you compute the probability that none of them occurs ?

Comment: Hint: Use DeMorgan's laws and resolutely refuse to use FOIL. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/66488/15941) and the comments following it.