# What Does Taking The Definite Integral Of This Function Mean?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, definite-integrals

I want to try to understand the game below a bit better.

---

The game is this: there are three locked doors, and at the beginning of the game you get either 1 or 2 keys.  You use the keys to unlock the dooor, open it, and collect object O from behind the door.  There are 4 possible events, listed below.

- Event A = get 1 key, object O is behind a door, I pick the door out of three with object O
- Event B = get 2 keys, object O is behind a door, I pick 2 out of 3 doors, object O is behind one of the doors I pick
- Event C = get 2 keys, there are two object O's behind 2/3 doors, I pick two doors and both have object O behind them
- Event D = don't get object O, either from some combination of events of it not appearing behind the door(s), or I don't pick the chest containing it.

There is no event where object O is behind all 3 doors.

Event A, B, C, and D are mutually exclusive

- K<sub>1</sub> = P(getting 1 key)
- K<sub>2</sub> = P(getting 2 keys)
- P(Object O "deciding" to be behind a door) = 0.08

  ---

set K<sub>2</sub> = x; K<sub>1</sub> = (1-K<sub>2</sub>); 1 ≥ K<sub>2</sub> ≥ 0

- $P(A) = (1-x)(0.08)(1/3) = (1-x)(2/75)$
- $P(B) = (x)(0.08)(2/3) = (2/75)x$
- $P(C) = (x)(0.08)(0.08)(2/3) = (8/1875)x$

$P(A U B U C) = P(winning)$

[image]
[image]

[Shortcut shown by /u/sasha](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66483/422650)

[WolframAlpha short way (above) input/output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-((1-((1-x)(2%2F75)))(1-((2%2F75)x))(1-(((8%2F1875)x))))

[WolframAlpha long way: P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(AB)-P(AC)-P(BC)+P(ABC)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((1-x)(2%2F75)%2B(2%2F75)x%2B(8%2F1875)x)-(((1-x)(2%2F75))*((2%2F75)x))-((1-x)(2%2F75))*((8%2F1875)x)-((2%2F75)x)*((8%2F1875)x)%2B((1-x)(2%2F75))*((2%2F75)x)*((8%2F1875)x))

Comparing equations, they are the same.

---

I graphed P(winning), where the x-axis is the probabilty of getting two keys (1 ≧ x ≧ 0), and the y-axis is the probability of winning.  P(winning) = {0.0266 for x = 0 ; 0.0308 for x = 1}.

$$\int_{0}^{1} P(winning) = 0.028624$$

Although the number of keys I can receive (0 or 1) is descrete, the probability of getting 2 keys is continous and random.  Intution tells me I would get an average of 1.5 keys per game.  If I let $X$ be 0.5, P(winning) = 0.028566.

From my understanding, taking the integral of a probability function yeilds probability density.  Yet, it makes no sense that I would have a 2.86% chance of getting 2 keys 0 to 100% of the time (it should be 1).   The area under the curve (from 0 to 1 nor from -infinity to infinity) converges to a number.

Exactly what, if anything, does that integral tell me?

Comment: I don't understand the $0.08$ factor - surely with this, you have a non-zero probability of object O being behind none of the doors?

Comment: $$\bbox[yellow, border:2px solid red]{\text{Please use MathJax}}$$

Comment: There is an 8% chance that object O will be behind a door, and a 92% chance that a door will not have object O behind it.

Comment: @QHZ In that case there's a probability $(0.92)^3=0.778688\cdots$ that there will be no object O behind any of the doors

Comment: @JohnDoe so are you saying that the formula for P(winning) is not correct?  If there's an underlining problem with how I went about this, correcting that first is paramount before going to the integral.

Comment: I am saying that the initial assumption you made is incorrect, or the model you have made to fit this assumption is incorrect. If indeed that $0.08$ is meant to be there, then that means that your $P(winning)$ _is_ correct, and it makes sense intuitively - there is a very good chance that there are no keys behind any doors.

Comment: @JohnDoe I relize that in my equation for P(winning), I included P(ABC).  Due to each event being mutally exclusive, that should be 0.  However, when I put it into WolframAlpha, I left it in there, and the x for that portion was included.

Yet, the graph of the function 
 (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t6ht4jkwp1) makes sense.  If P(K2) = 0 (I only get one key), P(B) and P(C) are 0, so only P(A) applies.  The opposite is true if K2 is 1.

Comment: Yes ,exactly - P(ABC) should be $0$ if you want it to fit the wording of the question, but is not $0$ if you follow the maths. The reason why the graph is wrong is because adding in this $0.08$ probably just changes the scale of the thing, while keeping the shape the same.

Comment: What is the origin of this problem? It is not really possible to answer right now since there is a conflict between the wording of the question and the mathematical framework with which the problem was set up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75933/discussion-between-qhz-and-john-doe).